# Eigenvalues of the endomorphism $P\mapsto(X − a)(X − b)P′ − nXP$ of $\Bbb R_n[X]$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following question:

> Let $E_n$ be the real linear space of polynomials of degree less or equal to $n$ with real
> coefficients. Let $u$ be the function defined on $E_n$ by $$u(P) = (X − a)(X − b)P′ − nXP,$$
> where $a,b ∈\Bbb R.$ Show that $u\in\operatorname{End}(E_n).$ Compute the eigenvalues of $u$ and for each
> eigenspace a basis. Find the kernel of $u$ and the set of polynomials $P$ such that $u(P) = 1.$

I am clueless about it, mainly in the part of finding the eigenvalues of $u.$
I wonder if I should find some $X = C$ in order to get an easier expression for lambda or there are other ways to get more generic expression.

Moreover, I tried to convert this expression to matrix form, in canonial basis, but as $n$ is bigger the dimensions are bigger as well, and calculating the determinant becomes irrelevant.

I would like to get some help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Are you clueless about the first question : Show that $u \in 
 End(E_n)$ as well ?

Comment: No, I only need help about the part of finding eigenvalues. @JeanMarie

Comment: Yes, finding the matrix with respect to canonical basis is a good way.

Comment: Hint: find the polynomial solutions of the corresponding differential equation.

Comment: But it becomes impractical when it comes to higher order of P (=n)

Comment: The matrix becomes indeed impratical. Not the 1st order linear ODE. It might even be a duplicate. https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=polynomial+solutions+differential+equation

Comment: I tried to go the way of differential equation, but the solution of this type of homogeneous differential equation is en exponent, but $P \in P_n(x)$

Comment: No, the solution is of the form $c(X-a)^\alpha(X-b)^\beta$ with $\alpha,\beta$ (of sum $n$) depending on $\lambda,$ and you have to select the values of $\lambda $ for which these exponents are non-negative integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint :

Let $s=a+b, p=ab$.

Due to the fact that

$$\begin{cases}u(X^k)&=&(k)(-(a+b)X^{k}+abX^{k-1})+(k-n)X^{k+1},& \text{for} \ k>0\\
u(X^0)&=&u(1)=-nX\end{cases}$$

the matrix associated with $u$ with respect to the canonical basis is

$$M=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
0&p&0&0&\cdots\\
-n&-s&2p&0&\cdots\\
 0&(1-n)&-2s&3p&\cdots\\
0&0&(2-n)&-3s&4p&\cdots\\
0&0&0&(3-n)&-4s\ddots&\ddots\\
0&0&0&0&\ddots&\ddots
\end{array}\right)$$

**Edit 1 :** While this matrix looks a little weird, its eigenvalues and eigenvectors are rather simple. An online Computer Algebra System ([SAGE](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/)) gives, in the case $n=3$, with the following instructions :

```
var('a b n')
s=a+b;p=a*b;n=3;
M=matrix([[0,p,0,0],
      [-n,-s,2*p,0],
      [0,(1-n),-2*s,3*p],
      [0,0,(2-n),-3*s]]);
v=M.eigenvectors_right();v
```

the eigenvalues

$$\lambda_1=-3a, \lambda_2=-3b, \lambda_3=-(a+2b), \lambda_4=-(2a+b)\tag{1}$$

(sanity check : their sum is indeed equal to the trace $-6s$)

with resp. associated eigenvectors :

$$V_1=\pmatrix{b^3\\-3b^2\\3b\\-1}, V_2=\pmatrix{a^3\\-3a^2\\3a\\-1},V_3=\pmatrix{a^2b\\-(a+2b)a\\(2a+b)\\-1},V_4=\pmatrix{ab^2\\-(b+2a)b\\(a+2b)\\-1}\tag{2}$$

One can guess from this particular case, the general form of the eigenvalues (see below), and their associated eigenvectors.

---

**Edit 2 :** if, as advised by @Anne Bauval, you choose to consider instead the differential equation, the eigenvalues/eigenvectors equation :

$$u(P)=\lambda P$$

can be written under the form :

$$(X-a)(X-b)P'-nXP=\lambda P$$

$$\frac{P'}{P}=\frac{u}{X-a}+\frac{v}{X-b}\tag{1}$$

for constants that are $u=\frac{na+\lambda}{a-b}$ and $v=\frac{nb+\lambda}{b-a}$

Integrating (1) gives :

$$\ln(|P(x)|)=u\ln(|X-a|)+v\ln(|X-b|)+\ln(c)  \ \text{for a certain} \ c > 0 $$

$$|P(X)|=c|(X-a)^{u}||(X-b)^{v}|\tag{2}$$

(we can drop the absolute values by taking $c \in \mathbb{R}$).

For $P(X)$ being a solution, one needs to have $P(X) \in E_n$, i.e., $P$ must have positive integer exponents ; for example, we must have :

$$u=\frac{na+\lambda}{a-b} \in \mathbb{N} \iff \lambda=u(a-b)-na$$

explaining that, taking successively $u=0$, $u=1$, etc... we get all the eigenvalues : $\lambda = -na, \ -b-(n-1)a, ...$, etc.

In particular, the components of vectors in (2) correspond to the four 3rd degree polynomials :

$$(x-a)^3(x-b)^0, \ (x-a)^0(x-b)^3, \ (x-a)^2(x-b)^1, \ (x-a)^1(x-b)^2.$$

Comment: The result of u(x) is $ (1-n)x^2 -(a+b)x + ab$, so how $M_{0,1}$ equals to zero?
Did I missed something like elementary action being made?

Comment: Probably you have that indexes start from 1 in your mind so I meant $M_{1,2}$ which is zero, but when you calculate u(x) you get: $ (1-n)x^2 -(a+b)x + ab$, which indicates that the value on the first row, second column should be ab. 
So I wonder if some manipulation being made on the matrix.

Comment: You are perfectly right. I had made several errors. Fixed  now (so I think...)

Comment: The general expression of u after placing $x^k$ is: $$ u(x^k) = (k-n)x^{k+1} -k(a+b)x^k +kabx^k $$
From this form you can understand that this matrix won't be diagonal or triangular matrix, which in this case make the chances to find a close expression for $\lambda$ to be negligible. I wonder if there is another way which doesn't involve matrix calculus.

Comment: Oh ok I didn't figure it out in that way, it seems to be clear now.
Thank you very much both!

Comment: Oh ok now Im just on to something. I forgot to note that X is the variable of P, which means that P is written like $P(x)$. Based on that, the solution remains the same or the idea of seperating those variables cannot be used? @Jean Marie

Comment: Indeed, you have to use a different name for the indeterminate $X$ and for the variable $x$. But the solution remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

As commented soon after you asked, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $u$ iff some nonzero polynomial $P\in\Bbb R_n[X]$ is a solution of the ODE
$$(X-a)(X-b)P'=(nX+\lambda)P,$$
i.e. (assuming $a\ne b$) iff
$$(X-a)^\alpha(X-b)^\beta\in\Bbb R_n[X],\text{ where }\alpha=\frac{\lambda+na}{a-b},\beta=\frac{\lambda+nb}{b-a}.$$
This is equivalent to
$$\lambda=-ka-(n-k)b\text{ for some }k\in\{0,1,\dots,n\}.$$